# Nativescript webpack fails to build

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript

Project was happily building with tns run android

To reduce startup time, I have installed

npm install --save-dev nativescript-dev-webpack

npm install

and then
tns run android --bundle

and getting below error.
.............
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.
  .............

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.business.bapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~6.1.0",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-pro-ui": "^3.4.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^3.7.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~4.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.3.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.17.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

more details about the error :

```
> :app:preDebugBuild > Resolve files of :app:debugCompileClasspathipt\xxxxxxx\node_modules\tns-core-modules-w
E:\xxxxxx\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns\gen\com\telerik\widget\list\ListViewDataSourceAdapter_vendor_77572_32_ListViewDataSourceAdapter.java:41: error: getItemViewType(int) in ListViewDataSourceAdapter_vendor_77572_32_ListViewDataSourceAdapter cannot override getItemViewType(int) in ListViewDataSourceAdapter
        public int getItemViewType(int param_0)  {
                   ^
  overridden method is final
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nativescript-pro-ui` is deprecated, remove that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this error by removing

"nativescript-pro-ui": "^3.4.1",

from package.json

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/1166) post. While I was reading [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/1166) post, Manoj replied on the same lines. Thanks Manoj.

But now other error related to android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffff6
has appeared, for which I might open another post.

Solution for the Resources Error is [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/914)